# .append on Large String of HTML Takes Long Time In IE 10

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have been having issues with some jQuery code at work, and I do not have the exact code with me right now but I will do my best to give pseudo-code. I am relatively new to javascript so some of the syntax may be wrong.

I am dynamically creating an HTML list of distinct values for every column in a table then putting them in a menu that opens when you click the header of the column (functions like a table in Excel). So I have an array of strings, and I call a function with this line for every column (there are 12):

```
$(name of ul element).empty().append(myFunction(items, nColumnNum));
```

Then the function I call is below:

```
myFunction(items, nColumnNum) {
    var r = "";
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        r += "HTML with <li> tag with checkbox and label inside"
    }
    return r;
```

Now I have done some basic analysis, and I know that 'myFunction' is not what is taking so long. The part that takes long is the '.append' function call. This goes very fast in Firefox, but in IE 10 it takes about 1.5 seconds when I am working with about 2200 items in the 'items' array. Since a couple of columns have this many items and I have 12 columns, this takes a long time. I have tried individually appending each list element (though I figured that wouldn't work) and I have tried setting the innerHTML instead of '.append' but none of it works.

Is there some sort of bug in the IE engine for this kind of thing and, if so, is there a workaround for this situation? Or is there just a more efficient way to do this?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: String concatenation is always slow when you get above certain numbers. Is it realistic for an end user to look through that many items?

Comment: Yes this functionality is possibly the most important part because it is used to search through items in our inventory. So, for example, one could go through all of the serial numbers and pick the appropriate item(s) they need from that list. And the string concatenation (at least within that function called 'myFunction') is not taking very long at all.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the fiddle related to it, that works fine on IE as well.

Let have an example of having items

```
var items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13];
items.length = 2200;
```

The JS code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#list_elements").empty().append(myFunction(items, 10));
});

function myFunction(items, nColumnNum) {
    var r = "";
    var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        r += "HTML with <li> tag with checkbox and label inside"
    }
    return r;
}
```

The html code:

```
<ul id="list_elements"></ul>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f69Pk/)

Comment: @user3367400, are you fine with the explanation? Or any doubts? :)